# Jquery Mobile is enough for all devices?

Tags: jquery, mobile

Im pretty new to a mobile web development and currently teaching myself jquery mobile. From my understanding, a simple jquery mobile app loads 3 libraries that are core jquery, jquery mobile.js and jquery.mobile.css.

Before, I used to use css media types and core jquery to make my web application compatible with all devices. Now by loading those 3 libraries above, my web application will react exactly the same in all devices no matter its a tablet, phone or laptop?

Thank you!

Comment: *"my web application will react exactly the same in all devices no matter its a tablet, phone or laptop"* that's the idea, but you should probably test it anyway.

Comment: ideally yes. Ultimately its a framework with which uses traditional jQuery as its backbone. But since everything is not ideal in this web world you should test it once :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will.

jQuery Mobile is a API for implementing web apps that look like native mobile apps, and it will look fine at phones and tables, but for the laptop is better to use the usual libraries.

An example: I developed a website and used jQuery Mobile for the mobile version, in a different html file. When the server identifies that the client is using a mobile device it automatically returns the .html with the mobile implementation, but, if the user is using a desktop, it returns a .html with a normal page.